# How can I reformat a USB

Tags: disk-utility, disk-format

I used by USB to add as iso file into it.

```
sudo dd bs=4m if=my.iso of=/dev/disk1
```

Now I want to get the USB back to normal. but the erase button in Disk Utility is disabled. How can I reformat this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following page has a lot of explanation on it but I've provided the quick steps below. Side note, try verify and repair and fix permissions in the app first to see if that does it.

[Erase disk via terminal](http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/disk-management-from-the-command-line-part-1)

Start in terminal with this command:
diskutil list

Next verify and repair the usb drive with this command putting the disk name I where it says {volume name} (no brackets):
diskutil verifyVolume /Volumes/{volume name} diskutil repairVolume /Volumes/{volume name}

If good so far, try erasing with this command, replacing disk identifier with the name from the list in the first step (eg disk2):
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Test /dev/{disk identifier}

Comment: Please add the solutions here in case the referenced site goes offline, deletes the page, changes the URL structure, etcetera.

Comment: Good point, sorry about that.

Comment: Keep the reference of course, and you can put the text as a citation. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Incase others encounter the same problem. I needed to unmount the disk with `sudo umount /dev/disk1` undertake your steps